# Php - Only show last part of value

Tags: php

I have a value from my database: **250.00$ 100x100cm** or **1960.00$ 500x500cm**

How do I make it so that it cuts away the price and only shows the measurements?

So it should only print out: **100x100cm** or **500x500cm**

I hope that's easy enough to understand.

Comment: lol, everyone beat me to it. Looks like explode will do...

Comment: Why are you getting the two values in one string anyway? Normalization is your friend, I'd always do 1NF unless there's a very good reason not to as it makes this kind of problem moot and is practically free. You wouldn't try to fit two integers into one, would you?

Comment: @delnan - obviously you haven't worked on many projects other than ones you started yourself.  If you had, you'd know there are a LOT of times you get stuck w/ data & databases that are poorly formatted/written.  Sometimes, you don't even have database access, which - like in this case, would require you to have a php solution.

Comment: @Dave: Obviously, changing the schema yourself is only possible if you're in charge. But I assume this is the case here, as someone as experienced as OP hopefully isn't working professionally on someone else's serious project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$value = "250.00$ 100x100cm";
$value_parts = explode(" ", $value);
echo $value_parts[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode( ' ', $value);` and pull the value from `[1]` in the resulting array.

```
echo array_pop( explode( ' ', '250.00$ 100x100cm' ) ); // 100x100cm
```

My example is doing something similar - using `array_pop()` I'm retrieving the value of the last index in the resulting array from `explode()` and returning it to be `echo`'d.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that's a single space separating the pieces and there are no other spaces:

```
list($price, $measurement) = explode(" ", $value, 2);
```

Note that the price is optional if you don't want it:

```
list(, $measurement) = explode(" ", $value, 2);
```

And the "2" is just for a bit of safety in case the measurement has a space.

Answer (score 1):

if thats always the format I would try the explode php function. Something like;

```
$array = explode("$ ", "250.00$ 100x100cm");
```

You can then just echo out which part of the array you need...

Answer (score 0):

Is it always going to be a three digit number?
`echo substr($string, -7);`
Otherwise you might want some regex
`preg_match("!\d+x\d+cm!", $value);`

Answer (score 0):

If you always have a space between the price and dimensions, you can use

`$newVar = explode(" ", $yourVar);` to split the value by a space and then just use `echo $newVar[1]` to show your dimensons.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($values as $value) {
  list($price, $size) = explode(' ', $value);
  echo $size;
}
```